# Delete from table based on subquery result

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-delete

It's showing the error as:

> error 1241:operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
DELETE FROM invoices
WHERE CLIENT_ID = (
                    SELECT * FROM  CLIENTS
                    WHERE state="OR"
    )
```

Comment: its showing the error as error 1241:operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DELETE FROM invoices WHERE CLIENT_ID = ( SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM CLIENTS WHERE state="OR" )
```

where clause in your case doesn't match with the result set in subquery. You are selecting * (all columns), you need to select the column which you are trying to match in the where clause